# Pandas Combining multiple Columns to Array results in ValueError

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas

I want to combine multiple columns of a Dataframe to one, containing an Array of those columns.

Simple Example of this:

```
sn |  a  |  b  |  c  |
---+-----+-----+-----+
a1 |  1  |  1  | None|
```

to

```
sn |  a  |  b  |  c  |    array  |
---+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
a1 |  1  |  1  | None| [1,1,None]|
```

I want to do this because I use Pandas (and SQL-Alchemy) to parse my data and write the Dataframe into a Postgresql-Table using Dataframe.to_sql. I tested this using numeric[], text[], integer[] etc. -columns in Postgres and to_sql replaces None with NULL, so this works exactly as intended.

To achieve this I wrote this simple function:

```
def timeseries(collist):
output = []
for col in collist:
    if str(col) in ['nan','None','NaT']:
        col = None
    output.append(col)
return output

dataframe['arraycolumn'] = dataframe.apply(lambda row: timeseries(row[collist1]), axis=1)
```

Nothing to complain about until I wanted to save timestamp-arrays (before simply saved as text[]). I get those timestamps in a bad format and use pd.to_datetime(df['timestampcolumn']) because Postgresql prefers ISO-Timestamps (trying to save this in timestamp[] column). But after casting with pd.to_datetime my function does not work anymore.

```
collist = ['a','datetime']
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda row: timeseries(row[collist]), axis=1)

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (...), indices imply (...)
```

I prepared a ipynb: https://github.com/cherryskizz/pandasarrayproblem/blob/master/theproblem.ipynb

I tested this with Python 3.4.4, 3.5.2, pandas 18.1 and 19.0.

I could write an function that parses those columns without use of pd.to_datetime, but maybe there are any other ways to solve this? Is there maybe a Pandas Function to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating a bit it looks like there is a bug when it tries to create the new DataFrame, for some reasons index and columns get mixed up. However it worked for me when I did this:

```
# transpose and apply column wise
df['c'] = df.T.apply(lambda row: timeseries(row[collist]), axis=0)
```

Pretty weird but for me it worked.

Comment: Weird indeed but it works. Thanks for your effort, but I will let this question open for now. Maybe someone can explain why index and columns get mixed up or find another solution for this.